# get result in descending order of 3 joined table

Tags: php, sql

**Query code is:**

```
$output="SELECT firstname, cnumber, raddress,pincode,state,country,heducation,ssc,practiceone,addressone,daysone,image 
    FROM doctor 
    JOIN addprofile ON doctor.id=addprofile.login_id 
    JOIN consultation ON doctor.id=consultation.login_id 
    ORDER BY id DESC";
```

**Question is:**

How to get result in descending order of 3 joined table with primary id of first table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add DBMS

Comment: Which is your first table primary key?

Comment: `ORDER BY doctor.id DESC`

Comment: My first table is doctor with primary key id.

Comment: Thanks a lot M Khalid Junaid. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested re-write:

```
ORDER BY doctor.id DESC
```